# How do I make this sed script a "one liner"?

Tags: bash, sed

I would like this script

```
sed -i "/INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP/,/version_added/ {
    /default/a\    linux:\n      '8': \/usr\/local
    }" base.yaml
```

rewritten to fit one line. Here's what I tried:

```
sed -i "/INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP/,/version_added/ {/default/a\    linux:\n      '8': \/usr\/local}" base.yaml
```

but it isn't working. I'm currently being harassed by this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

Comment: Use a separate `-e ''` for each line of `sed` program.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: one-liner questions; Stack Overflow's scope limits involve practicality; reducing readability to increase terseness is an inherently impractical as anything.

Comment: Any one liner worth it would use something like [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) instead of trying to apply regular expressions to yaml data. Provide a sample input file and desired results for that, though.

Comment: That is a one liner: it is one command that you can execute at the shell prompt as a unit.  It's just a multi-line one-liner. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ANSI C string -- with `$''` -- can contain backslash escapes, like `\n` -- so you can have a newline in `sed`'s arguments while still having the shell command *invoking* `sed` be only one line.

```
sed -i $'/INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP/,/version_added/ {\n    /default/a\\    linux:\\n      \'8\': \\/usr\\/local\n    }'
```

---

Insofar as your *real* goal is to build a RUN command for a Dockerfile, you can use `jq` to tell you how to escape any arbitrary command -- including multi-line commands -- as JSON:

```bash
printf '%s\0' sed -i "/INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP/,/version_added/ {
    /default/a\    linux:\n      '8': \/usr\/local
    }" base.yml | jq -Rrs '"RUN \(. | split("\u0000") | tojson)"'
```

...emits as output:

```
RUN ["sed","-i","/INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP/,/version_added/ {\n    /default/a\\    linux:\\n      '8': \\/usr\\/local\n    }","base.yml"]
```

Comment: or to avoid extra escaping, one could replace literal newlines with `"$'\n'"` in the original double-quoted string

Comment: And how to escape this command for dockerfile ? Because when you run it in the RUN directive it breaks everything

Comment: @Jacob If _that's_ what you needed you could have kept the original multi-line command in the first place. `RUN ["sed", "-i", "/INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP/,/version_added/ {\n    /default/a\\    linux:\\n      '8': \\/usr\\/local\n    }", "base.yml"]` and there you are.

Comment: @Jacob, (...if you'd _told_ us that was your goal in the question we could have gotten to an answer that was useful for you much faster).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP/,/version_added/!b;/default/a\   linux:\n      '\''8''\': \/usr\/local' file
```

The range is negated and those lines that do not match are left as is.

This allows the append command to follow the match without the need of  parens. If the parens were there the one liner would need to be split into two `-e` strings as the `a` command must end in a newline (the `-e` option emulates a line ending in a newline).

Also the whole one liner is enclosed in single quotes, making it less likely to incur problems inadvertently introduced by the shell.

N.B. The idiom `'\''` punches a hole to the shell behind and provides a single `'` (the shell needs to escape the `'` and thus the `\'`).